# How can I get the right native language?

Tags: .net, vb.net, localization

In a vb.net application, I have a combobox that I want to fill with all the countries of the world.

I used this piece of code to fill the combobox :

```
For each ci In CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    Dim ri as RegionInfo
    'Avoid null exception
    Try
        ri = New RegionInfo(ci.LCID)
    Catch
        Continue For
    End Try
    ri = New RegionInfo(ci.LCID)
    Me.ComboBoxCountries.Add(ri.ThreeLetterISORegionName + " - " + ri.EnglishName + " / " + ri.NativeName)
Next
```

So Basically, the goal is to have, for example, in my list :

*ESP - Spain/España*

But, since Spain has multiple cultures/languages (Catalan, Castilian, Basque, Galician etc.), I have, instead :

*ESP - Spain/Espainia*

*ESP - Spain/España* (This is Castilian)

*ESP - Spain/Espanya* (This is Catalan)

*etc.*

So, since there seems to be no priority, I would like to know how to get only the country and it's name in the first language of the country.

Basically, I find it odd to get a list of country starting from all the **cultures** in the world.

Comment: Don't forget that some countries (such as Switzerland) don't have a "first" language but have multiple official languages with equal status.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `AllCultures` but `SpecificCultures`, then you don't need to handle the exception. This LINQ query should work:

```
Dim countries = From ci In CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                Let ri = New RegionInfo(ci.Name)
                Let engCountry = ri.EnglishName
                Group ri By engCountry Into CountryGroup = Group
                Let first = CountryGroup.First()
                Order By first.ThreeLetterISORegionName
                Select String.Format("{0} - {1} / {2}",
                                     first.ThreeLetterISORegionName,
                                     first.EnglishName,
                                     first.NativeName)
Dim countryList As List(Of String) = countries.ToList()
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem, but you still showed me an other way to code it so I'll take it :). I still have some minor Languages, as far as I know : 

FRA - France/Frañs (Breton Language) instead of FRA - France/France

ESP - Spain/Espanya (Catalan Language) instead of España

Comment: @Marc-O: i don't understand. If i test it i get 128 countries but only `FRA - France / France` and `ESP - Spain / Espana`.

Comment: @Tim_Schmelter Maybe be it depends on the version of the library, the IDE or something like that... I'll try with something other than AllCultures or SpecificCultures. But this raises an interesting point.